# Audio loading in Windows Phone 8 browser

Tags: javascript, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

Is there a way to determine in Mobile IE (that is default browser on Windows Phone 8 phones), that audio file has been loaded? The "canplaythrough" event doesn't work on Mobile IE.